# Wordpress show result posts from query

Tags: php, wordpress

I am pretty new in Wordpress and I want to call a template to show the result posts from my query, which i have written in theme's functions.php:

```
$quotes = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'post', 'orderby'=>'title', 'order'=>'ASC', 'meta_value' =>$criterion));
```

I have the result and the template page but I don't know how to send them to the specific-template. How can I call template and send $quotes, for e.g. call_template(template_name, $quotes)

Answer (score 0):

Should just be a case of putting it in a function, returning $quotes, making sure that functions.php is included (if it isn't already) and then calling the function?

Unless you were planning to hook it into another wordpress function.

Answer (score 0):

if you are simply trying to show it on some page, than just make page template and query onto that page, and place a wordpress have_posts() loop, you should refer to template herirachy https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/

and you will know which php file from the theme directory the given page is loading from. or else there is an interesting plugin to know which template files are involved on a given page, this plugin https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/